# Is there a collection that doesn't subscribe to INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class that uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have a List bound to a grid. Every time that object changes it updates the values in the grid. However for historical reasons I want to add that object to a collection/list and bind to a history grid to show all the changes. However every list I have tried seems to subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged` so I only ever get the same amount of items in my history grid.

Is there a list/collection that doesn't subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're saying here. Lists themselves don't bind to INotifyPropertyChanged as far as I'm aware. Could you give some sample code?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow what you want but if you are wanting to bind an old version of the list then why not just clone it at the point in time you want to record the history?

Comment: Lists subscribe to INotifyPropertyChanged events so if an item changes it reflects that in the list doesn't it? I dont want that to happen in my case. I want seperate entries in a list for each change

Comment: The collection object itself wouldn't be subscribing to the INotifyPropertyChanged event. The Grid is. The Grid is supposed to be an reflection of the current state of the model it is bound to. It sounds like what you really want is a custom "History" model which subscribes to the original data model. Every time the original model changes, it would cause a new instance to be created by the History data model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your List is a list of references to a class, you will need to do a "deep clone" of the entire list in order to maintain a historical copy.  Otherwise, a copy of the list's contents will still be references to the "live" objects which are getting changed.  Doing this will require code such as:

```
// This requires a way to "Clone" your object...
List<YourClass> listCopy = originalList.Select(item => item.Clone()).ToList();
```

If the list contains value types (struct), you can just create a new `List<YourType>` and copy the original elements over.

```
// If your type is a value type, you can just copy the list directly...
var listCopy = originalList.ToList();
```

Also - this has nothing to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Lists, themselves, do nothing with the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Only problem is I have quite a few classes with a reference to MyClass so I have to serialize all my other classes

Comment: @Jon: Yes, if you want to preserve a full history, you'll pretty much be forcing a full serialization of your data at that point.  Otherwise, when you update your references, it would reflect in any "old" copy too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Mode=OneTime` in your binding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx#S3